# Receive null when calling on a class

Tags: java

I have to create a dog object and give it attributes and behaviors. I already did the attributes but the behaviors are not working as I want. I receive null.

```
public class JavaProgram{
    public static void main (String [] args){
        Dog dog1 = new Dog ("Luca", "mutt", 'M', 22, 5 );

        System.out.println("Dog1's name is " + dog1.getName() + ", its breed is " +
        dog1.getBreed() + ", its sex is " + dog1.getSex() + ", its age in months is " + 
        dog1.getAge() + ", its weight in pounds is  " + dog1.getWeight());

        System.out.println("When Dog1 eats it makes the noise " + dog1.getEating() +
        ", and when its barks the noise made is " + dog1.getBarking());
    }
}
```

```
public class Dog{

    private String name;
    private String breed;
    private char sex;
    //In months
    private int age;
    //In pounds
    private double weight;
    private String eating;
    private String barking;

    public Dog(String name, String breed, char sex, int age, double weight){
        this.name = name;
        this.breed = breed;
        this.sex = sex;
        this.age = age;
        this.weight = weight;
    }


    public Dog(String eating, String barking){
        this.eating = "Chomp, chomp, chomp";
        this.barking = "Woof, woof, woof";
    }


    public String getName(){
        return name;
    }

    public String getBreed(){
        return breed;
    }

    public char getSex(){
        return sex;
    }

    public int getAge(){
        return age;
    }

    public double getWeight(){
        return weight;
    }

    public String getEating(){
        return eating;
    }

    public String getBarking(){
        return barking;
    }
}
```

I should get "When Dog1 eats it makes the noise Chomp, chomp, chomp, and when its barks the noise made is Woof, woof, woof", but I get  "When Dog1 eats it makes the noise null and when its barks the noise made is "null"

Comment: You really should be able to figure that out by yourself. What does getEating() return? When is that field initialized? Do you ever call what initializes this field? That's the question you should ask yourself when reading and analyzing your code.

Comment: hey you, you pass the eating and barking argument pass in Dog dog1 = new Dog ("Luca", "mutt", 'M', 22, 5 );

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you meant to do:

```
public Dog(String name, String breed, char sex, int age, double weight){
    this("Chomp, chomp, chomp", "Woof, woof, woof");

    this.name = name;
    this.breed = breed;
    this.sex = sex;
    this.age = age;
    this.weight = weight;
}


public Dog(String eating, String barking){
    this.eating = eating;
    this.barking = barking;
}
```

You need to call the constructor (using `this()`) setting those values, as it won't happen automatically.

Answer (score 1):

This makes no sense :

```
public Dog(String eating, String barking){
    this.eating = "Chomp, chomp, chomp";
    this.barking = "Woof, woof, woof";
}
```

Parameters are not used to value fields : indeed you value fields with some compile time constant values : "Chomp, chomp, chomp" and "Woof, woof, woof".
According to your stated issue, you consider that any `Dog` have default values for `eating` and `barking` fields :

> I should get "When Dog1 eats it makes the noise Chomp, chomp, chomp,
>   and when its barks the noise made is Woof, woof, woof"
>
> `Dog dog1 = new Dog ("Luca", "mutt", 'M', 22, 5 );`

In this case a simpler approach is field initializers to value these fields. 
The other approach : chaining constructors(provided in the Simon answer)  is also correct but here we are not in a case of coupled constructors. So you can do it simpler.

```
private String eating = "Chomp, chomp, chomp";
private String barking = "Woof, woof, woof";

public Dog(String name, String breed, char sex, int age, double weight){
    this.name = name;
    this.breed = breed;
    this.sex = sex;
    this.age = age;
    this.weight = weight;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that dog1 object is created with the first Dog constructor

```
public Dog(String name, String breed, char sex, int age, double weight){
    this.name = name;
    this.breed = breed;
    this.sex = sex;
    this.age = age;
    this.weight = weight;
}
```

eating and barking field are not initialized in this constructor. You should also call the second constructor.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting null in the eating and barking field because you are calling the first constructor of the class and there those fields are not assigned any values.
You need to call the second constructor from the first.

```java
public Dog(String name, String breed, char sex, int age, double weight){
        this("", "");
        this.name = name;
        this.breed = breed;
        this.sex = sex;
        this.age = age;
        this.weight = weight;

    }
```

It is better to create one constructor with all fields and calling that constructor from other constructors with specific values.

```java
public Dog(String name, String breed, char sex, int age, double weight, String eating, String barking){
        this("", "");
        this.name = name;
        this.breed = breed;
        this.sex = sex;
        this.age = age;
        this.weight = weight;
        this.eating = eating;
        this.barking = barking;
}

public Dog(String name, String breed, char sex, int age, double weight){
      this(name, breed, sex, age, weight, "", "");

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to set the eating and barking in the first constructor itself and remove the second one as any Dog would be making the same noise and it doesn't make sense to have a constructor like that in my opinion

```
public Dog(String name, String breed, char sex, int age, double weight){
    this.name = name;
    this.breed = breed;
    this.sex = sex;
    this.age = age;
    this.weight = weight;
    this.eating = "Chomp, chomp, chomp";
    this.barking = "Woof, woof, woof"


}
```